# Getting a property value and passing it on to superclass

Tags: java

I need to get a property value from a property file and then pass it on to a superclass constructor. But since `super(value);` should be called first, where should I load the file and get the property value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to load the properties file first, you can only do this in a static method. It sounds like you really need a factory method.

```
public static MyType fromProperties(String filename) {
     Properties prop = new Proeprties();
     prop.load(filename);
     return new MyType(prop.getProperty("name"));
}
```

Comment: then i call `super(fromProperties(filename));` in the child class constructor?

Comment: That is the first option, in the second option you wouldn't need to do this as any values you need will have been loaded by the factory method.

Comment: but for that shouldn't prop be declared outside the method?

Comment: It needs to be declared outside the constructor as I do in the example

Answer (score 0):

you can use this approach:

```
class FooWrapper {
   private Foo foo;
   public FooWrapper() {
      Properties p = ...;
      foo = new Foo(p.getProperty("smth"));
   }

   public Foo getFoo() {
     return foo;
   }
}
```

or, if you can change Foo, rewrite it not to use string in the constructor, but to use special init() method:

```
class FooWrapper extends Foo {
   public FooWrapper() {
      Properties p = ...;
      foo = new Foo();
      foo.init(p.getProperty("smth"));
   }

}
```

Comment: Foo is an abstract class in my case. and moreover why should i create another object of Foo from my child class? when my child class is created, already superclass constructor is called. in anyway since Foo is abstract, i cant create an object of it from any child class.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly have a setter method in the super class for setting the value and then call that method from the child class for the initialization.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of options, the simplest being a protected init(TypeOfValue) method in the superclass, or using a factory method instead of the constructor in the child.

Answer (score 0):

You should load your property file once in your application and defining it as `static` public constant that you can access directly in your constructor:

```
public class Foo {

   public static final PropertyFile pFile = ...

   public Foo() {
      super(pFile.getProperty("..."));
      ...
   }     

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
public abstract class SuperClassLoad {

    private String name;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

public class ClassLoad extends SuperClassLoad {

    public ClassLoad() {
        super();
        Properties prop = new Proeprties();
        prop.load(filename);
        super.setName(prop.getProperty("name")));
    }
}
```

Comment: ya i had actually done this. But i wanted all subclasses to pass the value of a particular variable to the superclass. anyway thanks.